# Wide figure in two column - figure* will not be accepted

Tags: floats, two-column, wide-image

I have to make an assignment in two columns, which is working. Furthermore,  I want a wider figure in a two column document. I am trying to use:

```
\begin{figure*}
\end{figure*}
```

However, it gives an error, and does not show the figure. I am using the following document class:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
```

My preamble is as follows:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,autocite=inline,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}
\usepackage[labelfont={bf, it}]{caption}
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize, textfont=it}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\useunder{\uline}{\ul}{}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 9in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[L]{\fontsize{10}{12}}
\linespread{1.15}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\sloppy
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\usepackage[rightcaption]{sidecap}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{float}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The only error I see with your document is `Option clash for package geometry`, which you can solve by removing the line `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}`. The `figure*` works fine. Please, show us a complete compilable example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Replace your image with `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}`.  If it works, the problem is in your image.  If you still get the error, at least we shoulb be able to reproduce it.

Comment: you have posted three disconnected fragments of code (most of which is unrelated to figures) but not posted anything that anyone can run to debug your problem. Please post a small but complete document that shows the error (you can use `example-image` as the image as that is available for tests.